# Calculate $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{2^{xy}-1}{ |x|+|y| }$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate the following limit:
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{2^{xy}-1}{ |x|+|y| }$$

I know that the answer is $0$, but I don't know how to prove it.

I tried to use the squeeze theorem, but got stuck:

$$ 0\le \Bigg|\frac{2^{xy}-1}{ |x|+|y|}\Bigg|\le \Bigg|\frac{2^{xy}-1}{ |x|}\Bigg|$$

Is there a way to continue from here?

Comment: This approach turns out not to work, since the last expression is unbounded above when $x$ is close to $0$. Can you use the mean value theorem to estimate $2^{xy}-1=2^{xy}-2^0$?

Comment: @GregMartin No, we didn't learn it. What about $|\frac{2^{xy}-1}{ |x+y|}|$? It's also bigger than the initial expression

Comment: @Daniel You're right: my post was wrong. Sorry. I've deleted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use that : $2^{xy} = 1 + xy\log(2) + \mathcal{O}_0((xy)^2)$. The main problem is then to estimate $\frac{|x||y|}{|x|+|y|}$. But you can use that : $x^2+y^2 \geq 2|x||y|$. In particular :

$$ \frac{2|x||y|}{|x|+|y|} \leq \frac{x^2+y^2}{|x|+|y|} \leq \frac{(|x|+|y|)^2}{|x|+|y|} = |x|+|y| \rightarrow 0 $$

From here, you can conclude !

Answer (score 1):

For $x,y$ not both zero, let $f$ be given by
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{2^{xy}-1}{|x|+|y|}
$$
By AM-GM we have
$$
\frac{|x|+|y|}{2}\ge \sqrt{|xy|}
$$
hence letting $t=|x|+|y|$, we get
$$
\frac{t^2}{4}\ge |xy|
$$
Then for $x,y$ not both zero, we get
$$
\frac{2^{\Bigl({\large{-\frac{t^2}{4}}}\Bigr)}-1}{t}
\le
\frac{2^{-|xy|}-1}{|x|+|y|}
\le
f(x,y)
\le
\frac{2^{|xy|}-1}{|x|+|y|}
\le
\frac{2^{\Bigl({\large{\frac{t^2}{4}}}\Bigr)}-1}{t}
$$
and by L'Hopital's rule
$$
\frac{2^{\Bigl({\large{-\frac{t^2}{4}}}\Bigr)}-1}{t}
\;\;\;
\text{and}
\;\;\;
\frac{2^{\Bigl({\large{\frac{t^2}{4}}}\Bigr)}-1}{t}
$$
both approach zero as $t$ approaches zero from above.